# ASP.NET MVC AsyncController vs async await

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, async-await

Could somebody please explain what's the execution difference or performance benefit of using async await over AsyncController (Link [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598(v=VS.100).aspx)) for achieving asynchrony. I searched the Internet and Stackoverflow etc. and found that MVC 4 onwards we should use Tasks async await etc. and AsyncController is the thing of the past (and please feel free to correct me on this one if I've misunderstood).

Comment: You already asked this question [and deleted it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48944470/execution-level-difference-asynccontroller-vs-async-await), why have you asked it again?

Comment: Well for starters, `async/await` is just sugar syntax where the compiler generates all the nitty gritty `Beginxxx` and delegate handler for the underlying `IAsyncResult` source.  So for the most part there is little difference between older `IAsyncResult` and `async/await`.  Where it gets interesting is the context capture et al

Comment: @DavidG so you didn't like my question then and now? Is that because you don't understand it or because you deem question to be vague? I'd appreciate honest non-ego centric response. P.S. Question is slightly modified and I think you'd need to repost for new perspective

Comment: Did I say anything about liking your question? Now who is the one being ego-centric? I simply asked why you reposted the same question. Stack Overflow etiquette is to [edit] posts into better forms, not delete and make a new one.

Comment: @DavidG well I'm point centric rather than ego centric :) . If you didn't notice, first post didn't get any answers and this one did. I'm new to stackoverflow and not sure if changing a post gets noticed the same way. It is all about getting the first 50 points to have some liberty for me. After that it doesn't matter for me . :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now Asynchronous controllers are as easy to do as standard controllers, and thanks to the Task library and to the async/await keywords async calls are easier to implement and less error prone than before. This raises another problem: do not overuse them. If doing async with short tasks and with lots of requests the server will spend more time in thread switching than executing your code. So never do it just for the sake of it, but use some grain of salt and do performance testing.

AsyncController was dropped in MVC 4 wherein it is still there for compatibility for MVC3. You can also write simpler codes in await async and better way than subclassing AsyncController

Comment: _"If doing async with short tasks and with lots of requests the server will spend more time in `thread switching` than executing your code"_ - that's only true for CPU-bound tasks.   Typically what most people will be doing is performing an `async` database request or `WCF` call, both of which are I/O bound and so **use no thread**